# Magento new products widget

Tags: widgets, new-products

I am trying to create a CMS page which displays and paginates all the new products on a site. This first appears to be easy as there is a widget built in that lets you select if you want to use the pager, how many products you want per page and how many products you want in total. However in practise it doesn't work, it seems to ignore the pager and products per page options, however it does only return how many products total you have set.

Currently using the following code:

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" show_pager="1" products_per_page="8" products_count="16" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

This has been generated purely by Magento by selecting it from add widget in a CMS page.

Any ideas?